# Security header is not valid - Error in paypal - WHMCS

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, express-checkout, whmcs

I'm using custom Paypal billing agreement payment gateway in my WHMCS site. It was working fine for 1 year. I met some issues with generating transaction ID for in some scenarios. In order to check and fix the issue changed paypal environment to sandbox mode by providing the Sandbox API username, Password and Signature. But on calling 'SetExpressCheckout' I'm getting the following error.

```
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 119.0
[BUILD] => 40680762
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security error
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security header is not valid
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[ERRORS] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [L_ERRORCODE] => 10002
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => Security error
        [L_LONGMESSAGE] => Security header is not valid
        [L_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
    )
)
```

I tried it with different paypal sandbox accounts. But the result was same. When I'm using Live account with Live credentials the error will disappear and the token (REDIRECTURL) will generate. If I'm using sandbox with sandbox credentials the error is displaying.

What's the reason for this? I checked for trailing spaces, unwanted characters in the credentials I provided. Everything seems to be fine. Do I need to provide any settings in Paypal Account? How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means one of two things.  Either one of the values you've entered for the credentials is simply incorrect, or you're sending sandbox credentials to the live server or vice-versa.  Need to double check the endpoint that is being used for the API request to PayPal.  It sounds like maybe you're updating the credentials to use sandbox, but the endpoint is still hitting the live server.

Comment: Yes it was hitting live server. Now I fixed the issue

Comment: How you fixed that? Tell me

Comment: He's saying that he was sending sandbox credentials to the live server.  You just need to double check your values, and make sure that if you're using sandbox credentials, then you're sending the request to the sandbox servers and vice-verse.